# Javascript ngModel: No value accessor for ''

Tags: angular

I'm using plain javascript instead of TypeScript in a simple Angular 2 Get Started example with [(ngModel)], as shown below. It's giving me EXCEPTION: No value accessor for ''.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.11/angular2-polyfills.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.11/Rx.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.11/angular2-all.umd.min.js"></script>
<script>
(function(app) {
  app.AppComponent = ng.core.Component({
    selector: 'my-div',
    template: '<h1>Hello {{obj.a}}</h1>' + 
      '<div><input type="text" [(ngModel)]="obj.a"/></div>',
  }).Class({
    constructor: function() {
      this.obj = {a: "World"};
    }
  });
})(window.app || (window.app={}));

(function(app) {
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    ng.platform.browser.bootstrap(app.AppComponent);
  });
})(window.app || (window.app={}));
</script>
<body>
<my-div></my-div>
</body>
</html>
```

The error is produced with 2.0.0-beta.1 to 2.0.0-beta.11. If I were to use the original 2.0.0-beta.0, the above code runs without error.

I believe this is a bug with latest version of Angular 2. I wish I'm wrong, but no feature change should break something that works in 2.0.0-beta.0.

Here's plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/CqSeXeBpXgfgJUvBQ4mP?p=preview

Comment: So why does it work with 2.0.0-beta.0? Prove it. You have the plnkr.

Comment: As mentioned I don't know about JS. I found other examples and it seems this is not necessary in JS.

Comment: @real don't use the minified bundle. Minification has been broken since beta.1. If you change `angular2-all.umd.min.js` to `angular2-all.umd.dev.js` works fine.

Comment: Thanks Eric. That solved it.

Comment: You're welcome. Remember though that minification issues MUST be solved at some point, but for a long time hasn't be a priority and probably will continue like that for more.

Comment: This happens to me as well. I'm using webpack starter kit for angular2 rc1. can anyone suggest how to move forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Eric Martinez, I just needed to use angular2-all.umd.dev.js instead of angular2-all.umd.min.js.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/2.0.0-beta.11/angular2-all.umd.dev.js"></script>
```

That 1.0MB file though...